# MS Dynamics CRM : Quote Product to Product Relationship.

Tags: dynamics-crm

We are using `crm 2013` on premises.

I am having issues with customising the Quote Product (quote-detail) entity.  I have seen a lot of posts about the relationship and mapping of the Quote Product entity to the Opportunity Entity.  My problem is the mapping between the Quote Product entity and the Product entity.

A have data that I would like to pull from the product as soon as the quote product is created.  This data is crucial for generating quotes for customers (I am currently generating the quotes to be send to customers from reports).

**For example:**

I want to put the product description on the quote.  This I have done by querying the product description directly from the Product entity.  The problem is that sometimes a custom description must be added or the default description for the product must be changed for a specific quote.  To resolve this I would like to pull the product description from the Product entity and add it to a field in the Quote Product entity.  The sales people can then alter the product description as required.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you would not be able to accomplish your task using mapping. You will have to develop code to do it. To get required fields you can use OData endpoint to get info from Product entity during onchange event of productid lookup field and pull it to opportunity product fields.